# How do I use row or .fields as an alternative to asterisk() in jOOQ?

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have the same problem as the user in this issue https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8080. When our generated jOOQ code does not exactly match our DB schema, queries using `select(alias.asterisk())` throw errors because columns do not line up correctly.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : 633473bd597addd971f5b27e
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.toLong(PgResultSet.java:3328)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2540)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getLong(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultResultSet.getLong(DefaultResultSet.java:149)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorResultSet.getLong(CursorImpl.java:562)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultLongBinding.get0(DefaultBinding.java:3071)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultLongBinding.get0(DefaultBinding.java:3032)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$InternalBinding.get(DefaultBinding.java:1071)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorRecordInitialiser.setValue(CursorImpl.java:1581)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorRecordInitialiser.apply(CursorImpl.java:1517)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorRecordInitialiser.apply(CursorImpl.java:1432)
    at org.jooq.impl.RecordDelegate.operate(RecordDelegate.java:144)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.fetchNext(CursorImpl.java:1389)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.hasNext(CursorImpl.java:1365)
    at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl.fetchNext(CursorImpl.java:173)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractCursor.fetch(AbstractCursor.java:177)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractCursor.fetch(AbstractCursor.java:88)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:265)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:357)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:290)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetch(SelectImpl.java:2838)
```

The queries work normally when I use `.asterisk()`. The GitHub issue lists two workaounds, one using `TABLE.fields()` and another using `row(...)`. However, I'm unable to get these workarounds to work. Either I get a compilation error on the select statement:

```
            context
                .select(MY_TABLE.fields())
                ...
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
select((MutableCollection<out SelectFieldOrAsterisk!>..Collection<SelectFieldOrAsterisk!>?)) defined in org.jooq.DSLContext
select(vararg SelectFieldOrAsterisk!) defined in org.jooq.DSLContext
select(SelectField<TypeVariable(T1)!>!)   where T1 = TypeVariable(T1) for    fun <T1 : Any!> select(field1: SelectField<T1!>!): SelectSelectStep<Record1<T1!>!> defined in org.jooq.DSLContext
```

Or I get a result back with all null values:

```
    private companion object {
        private const val MY_TABLE_ALIAS = "table"

        private val MY_TABLE = TABLE
            .`as`(MY_TABLE_ALIAS)
    }
...
            context
                .select(MY_TABLE.fieldsRow())
                .from(MY_TABLE)
                .fetchInto(MY_TABLE)
                // values are all null in the toApi call
                .map(AvailabilityRegionsRecord::toApi)
```

Dialect: PostgreSQL
jOOQ version: 3.18.3

What am I missing here, and/or is there a different approach I can take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why `MY_TABLE.fields()` didn't work:

This method can't be called as you did in kotlin:

```kotlin
.select(MY_TABLE.fields())
```

Because `fields()` returns `Field<?>[]` and `select()` accepts a vararg. So, you need to use the [spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs). This is kotlin specific

```kotlin
.select(*MY_TABLE.fields())
```

#### Why `MY_TABLE.fieldsRow()` didn't work:

Using `fieldsRow()` will [nest your record](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/nested-records/), so this would require an adaptation to the record mapper. The projected type will be `Record1<Record[N]<T1, T2, .., TN>>`, not `Record[N]<T1, T2, .., TN>`

#### Better solutions

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76267587/521799), you can just omit the explicit projection using `select()` or even `selectFrom(MY_TABLE)`, though I always recommend using explicit projections, [see also this information from the jOOQ manual about `SELECT *`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/reference/dont-do-this/dont-do-this-sql-select-all/)

Comment: The spread operator was what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about just

```
select()
  .from(MY_TABLE)
  .fetchInto(MY_TABLE)
```

This generates SQL with only the columns your jooq schema knows about at the time.